# Perl UTF8 Concatenation Problems

Tags: perl, utf-8

I am having trouble concatenating a utf8 string to another after a string has been encoded and then decoded.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use utf8;
use URI::Escape;

# binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");

my $v = "ضثصثضصثشس";
my $v2 = uri_unescape(uri_escape_utf8($v));

print "Works: $v, ", "$v2\n";
print "Fails: $v, $v2\n";
print "Works: " . "$v2\n";
```

Here's the output:

```
Works: ضثصثضصثشس ,ضثصثضصثشس
Wide character in print at ./testUTF8.pl line 14.
Fails: ضثصثضصثشس, Ø¶Ø«ØµØ«Ø¶ØµØ«Ø´Ø³
Works: ضثصثضصثشس
```

If I use binmode utf8, as [perl's docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniintro.html) suggest, the warning message disappears but all 3 fail:

```
Fails: ضثصثضصثشس, Ø¶Ø«ØµØ«Ø¶ØµØ«Ø´Ø³
Fails: ضثصثضصثشس, Ø¶Ø«ØµØ«Ø¶ØµØ«Ø´Ø³
Fails: Ø¶Ø«ØµØ«Ø¶ØµØ«Ø´Ø³
```

What's going on?  How can I fix this?

P.S. I need it URL escaped.  Is there any way I can escape/unescape in perl like javascript does? For example, Perl gives me: %D8%B6%D8%AB%D8%B5%D8%AB%D8%B6%D8%B5%D8%AB%D8%B4%D8%B3

This unescapes to: Ø¶Ø«ØµØ«Ø¶ØµØ«Ø´Ø³

When I escape the same text with Javascript, I get: %u0636%u062B%u0635%u062B%u0636%u0635%u062B%u0634%u0633

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation of `URI::Escape`:

> [**uri_unescape($string,...)**](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI%3a%3aEscape#uri_unescape-string)
>   Returns a string with each `%XX` sequence replaced with the actual byte (octet).

It does *not* interpret the resulting bytes as UTF-8 and will not decode them, you will have to do this manually:

```
use Encode qw/decode_utf8/;

# untested
my $v2 = decode_utf8 uri_unescape uri_escape_utf8 $v;
...
```

Comment: Is there any way I can escape/unescape in perl like javascript does?  For example, Perl gives me: %D8%B6%D8%AB%D8%B5%D8%AB%D8%B6%D8%B5%D8%AB%D8%B4%D8%B3 --

This unescapes to: Ø¶Ø«ØµØ«Ø¶ØµØ«Ø´Ø³ --

When I escape with Javascript, I get: %u0636%u062B%u0635%u062B%u0636%u0635%u062B%u0634%u0633

Comment: @DemiImp, That's super weird. That's not legal application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoding, what browsers must use when building a URL from a form.

Answer (score 3):

`uri_unescape` is the inverse of `uri_escape`. It doesn't presume the bytes represent a UTF-8 string.

An inverse for `uri_escape_utf8` isn't provided. Maybe so you can handle errors?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use utf8;                     # Source code is UTF-8 encoded.
use open ':std', ':utf8';     # Terminal expects UTF-8.
use URI::Escape;

my $ov = "ضثصثضصثشس";

my $uri_comp = uri_escape_utf8($ov);

my $nv = uri_unescape($uri_comp);
utf8::decode($nv) or die;

print "$ov -> $uri_comp -> $nv\n";
```

```
ضثصثضصثشس -> %D8%B6%D8%AB%D8%B5%D8%AB%D8%B6%D8%B5%D8%AB%D8%B4%D8%B3 -> ضثصثضصثشس
```

Comment: `use open ':std', ':utf8';` binmodes STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR and specifies the default encoding layer for file handles.

Comment: @Nemo, `Encode::decode` can handle "any" encoding, while the latter only does UTF-8. As the text you omitted explained, "dealing with encodings other than UTF-8" is what the doc means by "general purposes". Four other differences: 1) The former returns the decoded string; the later decodes in place. 2) The former can decode invalid strings (by using a replacement character); the latter returns an error or croaks. 3) The former is probably slower than the latter. 4) The former requires a (Core) module; the latter is builtin.